# Retrieve pointer that can acess all the elements of arrays stored in a std::vector

Tags: c++, pointers, stdvector

Is it possible to have a pointer that points to the contiguous buffer that is used by a vector?

For example (see below please), here `std::vector<unsigned char*> vec` contains two differently sized `unsigned char*` pointers. I need to have a buffer pointer that points to all pushed data in this vector. I'd guess that this is possible as the standard guarantees that a vector uses a contiguous memory buffer, right?

P.S. are the two ways of printing the elements of the vector I use in this example fine? (the two for loops)

```
unsigned char* data1 = new unsigned char[3];
data1[0] = 'a';
data1[1] = 'b';
data1[2] = 'c';


unsigned char* data2 = new unsigned char[1];
data2[0] = 'x';

std::vector<unsigned char*> vec;
vec.push_back(data1);
vec.push_back(data2);

for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
    std::cout << vec[i];
}

std::cout << "\n";

for (auto iter = vec.begin(); iter != vec.end(); iter++) {
    std::cout << (*iter);
}
std::cout << "\n\n";


unsigned char* buffer = (unsigned char*) vec[0];
```

Does `buffer` point to all data in `vec`? *i.e.* `buffer[0] = a, buffer[1] = b, buffer[2] = c, buffer[3] = x` ?

Comment: `&vec[0]` is `unsigned char**` and casting it to `unsigned char*` looks dangerous.

Comment: Are you looking for [`std::vector::data`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/data/)?

Comment: Only pointers are pushed to the vector. What are pointed at are NOT pushed to the vector. Therefore "all pushed data" here is only the two pointers. Is this what you mean?

Comment: `std::cout << (*iter);` is dangerous because `char*` pointed at buffers that are not NUL-termintated is passed and out-of-range read will happen.

Comment: You seem to be asking two different questions, 1) is it possible to have a pointer to the data in a vector, yes 2) is it possible to have a single pointer to all the bytes in a vector consisting of two byte pointers, no.

Comment: Yes, the vector stores the pointers contiguously. Is that useful information? No, because the pointers point to an entirely different place that is not contiguous.

Comment: `unsigned char* buffer = (unsigned char*)&vec[0]` is wrong. `vec[0]` is an `unsigned char*`. `&vec[0]` is an `unsigned char**`. It should be `unsigned char** buffer = &vec[0];` and right after this  `cout << **buffer;` should print `a`. But this is pretty pointless anyway

Comment: ...or maybe you want `unsigned char* buffer = (unsigned char*)vec[0] `? It's pretty unclear what you want to achieve here.

Comment: `unsigned char* buffer =   (unsigned char*) vec[0];` does `buffer` point to all data in `vec`? i.e. buffer[0] = a,  buffer[1]=b,  buffer[2]=c,  buffer[3]=x ?

Comment: @MohammedZiad No it doesn't (as already stated).

Comment: `i.e. buffer[0] = a, buffer[1] = b, buffer[2] = c, buffer[3] = x ?`, no, as already pointed out in several comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Does `buffer` point to all data in `vec`? *i.e.* `buffer[0] = a, buffer[1] = b, buffer[2] = c, buffer[3] = x`?*

It doesn't. It points to the beggining of the array stored in first element of the vector.

> *Are the two ways of printing the elements of the vector I use in this example fine?*

They are not, those arrays are not null terminated, they can't be printed as strings.

> *Is it possible to have a pointer that points to the contiguous buffer that is used by a vector?*

Yes, it's possible.

If you'd like a pointer that can correctly access all the data in the vector, including individual elements of the unsigned char array members you'd want:

```
unsigned char **buffer = vec.data();
```

And the access:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    std::cout << buffer[0][i]; //indexing like a 2D array, albeit unbalanced
                                 //output: abc

std::cout << buffer[1][0]; //output: x
```

Note that I use a cycle to access each element of `data1` instead of simply treating it like a string, and this is because it is not a string, aka a null terminated char array.

Needless to say that you will need to know how many elements are stored in each array.

Alternatively you can null terminate them:

```
unsigned char* data1 = new unsigned char[4];
//...
data1[3] = '\0';
```

And

```
unsigned char* data2 = new unsigned char[2];
//...
data2[1] = '\0';
```

Here printing them like strings:

```
std::cout << buffer[0];
std::cout << buffer[1];
```

Using a null terminator has the extra benefit of allowing you to know the size of the arrays at any time using `strlen((char*)buffer[0])`.

Comment: But he has `(unsigned char*) &vec[0]`, not `(unsigned char*) vec[0]`

Comment: But now the first sentence of your answer is wrong.

Comment: `unsigned char* buffer =   (unsigned char*) vec[0];` does `buffer` point to all data in `vec`? i.e. buffer[0] = a,  buffer[1]=b,  buffer[2]=c,  buffer[3]=x ?

Comment: @MohammedZiad, no it points to the first element of the vector.

Comment: @MohammedZiad, I think this is what you want.

Comment: @anastaciu Many Thanks! So is it compulsory to add the null terminator? P.S. Please fix the typo in your answer data1-->data2

Comment: @MohammedZiad If you use the array as a null terminated string, then it must be null terminated. If you don't use the array as a null terminated string, then it doesn't need to be null terminated. Inserting a char pointer into a character stream is an example of using it as a null terminated string.

Comment: @MohammedZiad, fiexed, it, thanks, it's not mandatory, only if you'd like to treat those as strings, if not, and you only want to work with individual `unsigned char`s, it's fine without the null terminator. As eerorika just stated.

Answer (score -1):

You want the `data()` method on vector. It will return a pointer to the data, assuming that the vector size is greater than zero. If it is zero, then `data()` will return *something* but using it is undefined.

Read https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data